# Function addresses in MFC message maps

Tags: c++, mfc

Why are function addresses in message maps generated by the class wizard written with the name of the class explicitely mentioned?

For example:

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK1, &CMyDlg::OnClickedSomeButton)
```

instead of:

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK1, &OnClickedSomeButton)
```

or even:

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK1, OnClickedSomeButton)
```

All three variants compile correctly.

It's just curiosity.

Comment: I always thought this was a legacy issue with the early VS cpp compilers that after the macro expansion it needed the class qualification in order to correctly do the lookup but I'd be interested to learn why from one of the VS  dev team. The early VS compilers were not that standards compliant.

Comment: &CMyDlg::OnClickedSomeButton notation indicates a 'pointer to a member function'. That's not the same thing as a pointer to a function.

Comment: @EdChum: No, this is not the case. If indeed the message map entries were to need the class name, then that is already accessible through the introductory [BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x1t4dy1.aspx) macro. The true reason is what john mentioned: Pointers to functions and pointers to member functions are different things. [Pointers to member functions are very strange animals](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040209-00/?p=40713).

Comment: The first syntax is the only correct syntax for pointer-to-member-function, see [\[expr.unary\]p4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.unary#op-4). The other two are MSVC extensions.

Comment: It seems like it may be a case of just using a good programming practice, after all, using fully qualified name & syntax.

Answer (score 2):

> All three variants compile correctly.

Yes, they compile correctly...on MSVC. If you try to compile the second or third example in Clang (Microsoft compatibility mode) you will get an error.

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK1, &OnClickedSomeButton)
```

yields `Clang : must explicitly qualify name of member function when taking its address`

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK1, OnClickedSomeButton)
```

yields `Clang : call to non-static member function without an object argument`

It's definitely better to stick to the first form even if you never want to ship other than MSVC-compiled binaries - you might want to use tools like clang-tidy which require clang compilation. It is also the only [C++ standard-conformant way](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.unary#op-4) to pass a member function pointer. The other two work by Microsoft's extension.